# Tomcat stopping issue + Spring boot + service

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, service

I have 2 Spring boot projects running on same tomcat:

1. REST-API
2. Background Service (BS)

**Purpose**

1. REST-API : UI application uses this to get things done.
2. BS : Based on UI activity this service gets executed and gets things done on Real-time .

**Details**
BS is written as `while(1)` considering the purpose of the same.

***Tomcat Error***
1st Attempt:

```
Using CATALINA_PID:    /home/user/bin/pid/tomcat_pid  
Tomcat did not stop in time.  
PID file was not removed.  
To aid diagnostics a thread dump has been written to standard out
```

2nd Attempt:

> ```
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)  
>   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)  
>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)  
>  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  
>  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)  
>  at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)  
>         at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)  
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:492)  
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)  
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:406)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
> The stop command failed. Attempting to signal the process to stop through OS signal.
> Tomcat stopped.
> ```

**Problems:**
 1. When I restart tomcat, BS project will only be running and REST-API does not get started (I guess this happens because of `while(1)` it starts executing and not giving chance to start REST-API project )
 2. While stopping tomcat it does not get stopped in a single attempt, when we try to stop one more time then it gets stopped.

Comment: can you paste the tomcat log errors ?

Comment: @VasanthRaghavan I have edited question and added the tomcat log

Answer (score -1):

This exception  mostly indicates that there is no service listening on the IP/port you are trying to connect to, so ,you are trying to connect to the wrong IP/port, or the server is not started.

Comment: Is your tomcat server up and running ?

Comment: Yes once we deploy `BS` then it goes into hang state i.e, `catalina.log` do not write anything while `BS` logs are working fine.

Comment: is your application consuming too much memory ? that can cause these crashes potentially. Open the  catalina.bat file in /bin directory. Add the line :set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms1024m  -Xmx1024m where Xms is the initial (start) memory pool,Xmx is the maximum memory pool
Xss is the thread stack size